# Django: cannot import name “get_svn_revision”

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to install [**OSQA**](https://github.com/dzone/osqa), a Django application on *Linux Red Hat* (*Python 2.7* and **Djando 1.6**). I synchronized the databases and I restarted Apache without get any error.

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
python2.7 manage.py syncdb --settings=settings
python2.7 manage.py migrate --settings=settings --fake
$APACHE/restart
```

After I opened the site from the browser I get HTTP status "200" Error, and in the logs I get this error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module forum.middleware.extended_user: "cannot import name get_svn_revision"
```

([See complete Logs](http://pastebin.com/aGhTvHZt))

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue with OSQA, and restarting Apache solved it for me. I'm not sure why this happened though; sorry!